# ffmpeg png + mp3 = mp4, howto make all image in a folder + random mp3 file to mp4 video with name file mp4 is name of png file?

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

i have a folder with 10 file png and 5 file mp3, i want use ffmpeg convert png+mp3=mp4, random 5 file mp3 for 10 file png, name of file mp4 finish is name of file png. how to do it, please help!

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: This is a really broad question and asking for help about several things, so getting an answer is unlikely. Is there a specific task you need help with? Are you having trouble with random selection or the `ffmpeg` part?